# Pass Multiple Url Parameters to a Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

People visit this URL:
http://example.com/?c1=value1&c2=value2&c3=value3&c4=value4&kw=kwvalue

Inside that very page I have this link:
`<a href="http://site2.com/?c1=&c2=&c3=&c4=&kw=">Clic Here</a>`

All I want is autofill my link with value1, value2, value3, value4, kwvalue, so that the end result would be this:

`<a href="http://site2.com/?c1=value1&c2=value2&c3=value3&c4=value4&kw=kwvalue">Clic Here</a>`

Cannot use PHP, is a HTML document. 
**NOTE:** I´m not a programmer so I appreciate clarity and simplicity

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to create a link based on some JavaScript variables, you can construct the link based on concatenation.

This code takes your variables and glues them together with the `+` operator to make a string that holds the link. Then the string is assigned to the `href` attribute of your `<a>` element.

```
document.getElementById("Your link Id").href = "http://example.com/?c1="+value1 +"&c2="+value2 +"&c3="+value3 +"&c4="+value4 +"&kw="+kwvalue
```

Replace `Your link Id` with your link's id.

Comment: I tried to make it work but how the href field would look like? I mean, should be empty? 

`<a id="myid" href="">Clic Here</a>`

But when I do that my Optimizepres live editor undo that and replace it for this: `<a id="myid"></a>Clic Here`

Comment: No href is needed, I think. So `<a id="myid">clic here</a>` should work.

Comment: If you want, you can click the check-mark below the arrows on my posts to say that my post worked for you in a way the software can understand.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the parameters from your *querystring* (the part of the URL after the question mark) into the link on your page, you are going to have to use some programming.

It sounds like you want this to work on a static HTML document, which is not possible.

You will need some sort of environment (it doesn't have to be PHP) that allows for some programming.